# In rails, can I modify a record without EDIT action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a post route **"Vote"** and it is a member of **"Articles"** resources like this:

```
 resources :articles do
  member do
   post 'vote'
  end
 end
```

I want to check the user if he **"LIKED"** the article and then he clicked **"DISLIKE"**, I will modify the record based on the sent parameters. So can I do it without **"EDIT/UPDATE"** actions by just finding that record and modify it ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, just write corresponding action in controller.

Also if you do not have edit/update/destroy/etc i'd recommend removing routes for them:

```
resources :articles, only:[:index, :show] do
  member do
   post 'vote'
  end
 end
```

Comment: But I want you to clarify this ... I do not have "EDIT" action for "VOTE" table. So can I edit a record in "VOTE" without "EDIT" action. For example if the user "LIKED" something then later he clicked "DISLIKE", I will modify the record based on the sent parameters. How to do it ?

Comment: @steve tables do not have actions, they live inside database, in rails tables are represented by models. Controllers have actions, which are in a nutshell - just a function that is called when user makes some kind of request. Inside actions you can modify any model you like in any way you need. Just do not be confused by table, controller and model having similar name, they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

> I will modify the record based on the sent parameters

To add to `vasfed`'s answer, you'll have to stick to a [`member` route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes) as to pass the `article` `id` to the controller:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def vote
      @article = Article.find params[:id]
      # vote for article somehow
   end
end
```

You'll also be able to clear up your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles, only: [:index, :show] do
   post :vote, on: :member #-> url.com/articles/:id/vote
end
```

---

**Update**

To answer your comment, you're getting confused between `tables` and `models`.

The `votes` table has relatively little to do with the `vote` functionality. The functionality you want is scoped around an `@article`, hence why both `Vasfed` and I recommended having methods in the `articles` controller (you're voting on an *article*).

> So can I edit a record in "VOTE" without "EDIT" action.

In this case, you're not "editing" vote; you're editing the `@article` by applying a vote to it.

The answer `@Vasfed` gave shows that you can create a `vote` method in your `articles` controller to manage the action of voting for / against the `@article`.

If it were my app, I'd do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles do
   match :vote, via: [:post, :delete], on: :member #-> url.com/articles/:id/vote
end

#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def vote
       @article = Article.find params[:id] 
       if request.post?
          @article.liked_by curent_user
       elsif request.delete?
          @article.disliked_by curent_user
       end
       redirect_to @article
   end
end
```

Comment: Try to answer my comment to Vasfed, if you have an idea

Comment: By the way, I did not understand this line `post :post, on: :member`

Comment: `post :vote, on: :member` is a [member route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes) - `url.com/articles/:id/vote`